# RSA Encryption using public key in Android for a PHP server

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, public-key

I am trying to encrypt a string using the RSA public key encryption. I have a public key which  is:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7yyFgPV6Fk8JWngl3MIz\n1U2DMwKPNCRkeQ79g/qwKL0LP5aVkQUUxqYhX0mmQMWnT5t+7Hoc6UUxyjGSkI9o\nv0Q3oTSVtByIQDdySXZWihzjVjn3h98chevZuNNkJ4GNADHj5K/7LOWLpKSQJ2Hj\nIFdVrcKSjy4kiP/UMHgsfq0GWQAtGv8ebcybWuEf8rzTMndxmI96Nmz5PgPK7K75\nXbMgJlOMoMlXDsgmghpGzH8p10r/qHGlYi/COa4PZ7Pvbveg1BoH5LPy/8mLZ+Oa\n9owl10yBIoh9/H5KnijZ0Uq8MH0QdgQXekLC9sRh3uGTe69IQrGXzSv7tHe5fgv6\nnwIDAQAB\n-----END
>   PUBLIC KEY-----

I am using following code to encrypt it :

```
private String generateRSAEncryptedText(String publicKey) {
        String baseCredentials = email + "---" + password;
        try {
            return encryptRSA(context, baseCredentials, publicKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String getPublicKeyStringFromPemFormat(String PEMString, boolean isFilePath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        BufferedReader pemReader = null;
        if (isFilePath) {
            pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(PEMString)));
        } else {
            pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(PEMString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        }
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----") != -1) {
                while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.indexOf("-----END PUBLIC KEY") != -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    content.append(line.trim());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (line == null) {
            throw new IOException("PUBLIC KEY" + " not found");
        }
        Log.i("PUBLIC KEY: ", "PEM content = : " + content.toString());
        return content.toString();
    }

    public String encryptRSA(Context mContext, String message, String publicKeyString) throws Exception {

        String keyString = getPublicKeyStringFromPemFormat(publicKeyString, false);

        // converts the String to a PublicKey instance
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(keyString.getBytes("utf-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

        // decrypts the message
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(message.getBytes("utf-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        return Base64.encodeToString(dectyptedText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Using this, i am able to generate an encrypted text but the PHP server is not able to decrypt my encrypted text.

Server is working correctly as i am able to the whole exercise using a python script but it is not working for android.

Any idea what i might be doing wrong.. all help is appreciated.

Some other pointer:

1. I get the public key as a string from the server and it can be changed at any time so cant save it in a cert file.
2. I am using android.util.Base64 class for encoding.

Let me know if you need any other information.

**Working Python Code:**

```
import requests
import base64

def try_api():
    API_ENDPOINT = 'https://example.com/login.php'
    PUBLIC_KEY = None

    ###get_pulic_key###  
    payload = {'requestType':'getPubkey'}
    r = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, data=payload, verify=False) 
    mycookies = dict (r.cookies)
    #print mycookies

    res = r.json()
    PUBLIC_KEY = res[1]

    print "PublicKey\n", PUBLIC_KEY

    ###get_token###
    credential = prepare_credentials('abc@gmail.com', 'abctest', PUBLIC_KEY)
    print "Credential\n", credential

    cred_payload = {'requestType':'credentialLogin', 'credential':credential}
    r = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, data=cred_payload, cookies=mycookies, verify=False)
    #print r.text
    status, token =r.json()




def prepare_credentials(username, password, public_key):
    """
    Given username and password prepare the credentials
    """


    basecred = "%s---%s" % (username, password)
    #print "basecred\n", basecred
    basecred64 = base64.b64encode(basecred)
    #print "basecred64\n", basecred64
    basecred64encrypted64 = encrypt_RSA(public_key, basecred64)
    #print "basecred64encrypted64\n", basecred64encrypted64
    return basecred64encrypted64


def encrypt_RSA(public_key, message):
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
    from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(public_key)
    rsakey = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
    encrypted = rsakey.encrypt(message)
    return base64.b64encode(encrypted)

if __name__=='__main__':
    try_api()
```

Comment: You have *not*: 1) told us what "not able to decrypt" means; 2) shown as any PHP code; 2) shown us any of the supposedly working python code. At this point only random guesses are possible.

Comment: not able to decrypt means that the PHP code is not able to decrypt the encrypted message which is being sent from android app

Comment: If you don't want help that's fine.

Comment: @GregS : i have updated the python code.. i dont have PHP code.

Comment: From your post: "the PHP server is not able to decrypt my encrypted text". If the PHP server doesn't have the PHP code to decrypt the RSA than that's probably the problem ;) Your question is akin to me asking "why isn't my phone able to make phone calls?" whilst leaving out the important fact that the phone won't turn on.

Comment: @neubert: PHP server has the code to decrypt the encrypted text. If you read the question carefully it has a python code which executes without any problem (meaning PHP code is able to decrypt it).